# Starting an MVC4 basic template project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to start a new MVC4 C# project using the basic template, when I debug the project I get the "The resource cannot be found" error, how would I fix this so I just shows a blank page I can work on?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the URL it's sending you to after you hit the play button?  Sometimes if you're editing a view (.cshtml), when you hit play it'll try to open up the .cshtml file, which will give you a similar error. Check the url and go to the root (something like http://localhost:1234/ ..or whatever port yours defaults to).

Comment: I am at the default root page, this is a brand new empty project

Comment: Can you post the contents of the output window if you see any types of errors there?

Comment: I've put the error into  pastebin:
http://pastebin.com/B81N0jPX

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "Basic" template does not have any controllers or views in it. You have to create at least a HomeController and an associated view for a page to be displayed. If you want an example application to start from that has something to view without adding anything choose the "Internet Application" template.  It creates a default HomeController and and Index view as well as account logon pages.

Answer (score 6):

You need to add Controllers and View pages to just show something!

Add HomeController : Controller file

```
public string Index()
{
return "Hello";
}
```

if you run now, you will be able to see hello on the page